# 'document is undefined' error in javascript function

Tags: javascript

I'm working on an assignment in which there are 2 functions, each of which are supposed to take document as a parameter. I kept getting 'document is undefined' as an error in the console, so I took out 'document' as a parameter altogether from the two functions, and not only did the error go away, but my overall program is working.

However, now there is an autograder for the assignment that is telling me 'document is not defined' in my two functions. The first line of each function is a variable declaration like the below.
let faultyItems = document.getElementById("faultyItems");

Do I need to define document before calling it? And do I most likely need to put it back in as a parameter? Any advice would be greatly appreciated as I'm new to the DOM - thank you.

Comment: please provide your code

Comment: In browser environment you don't need to define `document` before using it, in node js you should, and you shouldn't name any other variable `document` as it's taken, if you can provide code samples I can help you more with the error.

Comment: you can't define a language keyword,could you provide your code to help also see the error

Comment: Hi turns out I needed to define document as "let document = window.document"